# How to drag a point and then use savestrategy in OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers-2, javascript, vector, wfs-t

Im trying to use the wfs-t in openayers using the savestrategy.
I have created a savestrategy and it works when I for example uses the DrawFeature Control to add a point. A new point is added to the database.
However, when I use the DragFeature control to move a point (in the same vector layer as I have added using DrawFeature) it doesnt work.

The response from Geoserver is

```
<wfs:InsertResult>
   <ogc:FeatureId fid="none"/>
</wfs:InsertResult>
<wfs:TransactionResult> 
  <wfs:Status> 
    <wfs:SUCCESS/> 
  </wfs:Status> 
</wfs:TransactionResult>
```

And to me that looks like for some reasons no information sent regarding the fid that should have been moved.

What could I havce done wrong?
BR
Mike

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the feature's state to UPDATE. If you want to do it by hand, here is a code snipped:

```
wfs.events.register('afterfeaturemodified', null, afterModified);

function afterModified(e) {
  // only set to update if state is NOT INSERT and NOT DELTE !!!
  if(e.feature.state!=OpenLayers.State.INSERT &&
     e.feature.state!=OpenLayers.State.DELETE) {
       e.feature.state=OpenLayers.State.UPDATE;
  }
}
```

The ModifyFeature Control does set the flag automatically in the  [setFeatureState method](http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Control/ModifyFeature-js.html#OpenLayers.Control.ModifyFeature.setFeatureState). I suppose that the the DragFeature does not.

Answer (score 0):

I changed to use the ModifyFeature Control instead of using the DragFeature COntrol and it worked like it should